# React unit test : test a blur event

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, tsx

I have a problem in one of my react jest unit test.
In my storybook everything is working well but I can't seem to test a proper UI reaction in my test.

The problem is that I have a custom dropdpwn that must close on a blur event (when you click outside of the parent div of this element) and it's working nicely in my storybook but not in my unit test.

Unit test code that is not working :

```
it('should close and reset dropdown when a click is produced outside of it', () => {
    render(<>
      <MultilevelDropdown {...multilevelDropdownProps} />
      <div> <a data-testid='outside-element'> Test </a> </div>
    </>);
    const multilevelDropdown = screen.getByText('Ajouter une démarche');
    fireEvent.click(multilevelDropdown);
    const group = screen.getByText('Matière');
    fireEvent.click(group);
    expect(screen.getByText('Polyamide Recyclé')).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('outside-element'));
    expect(screen.queryByText('Matière')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.queryByText('Polyamide Recyclé')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(multilevelDropdown).not.toHaveClass('dropdown__trigger__open');
  });
```

Component TSX code :

```
const MultilevelDropdown = ({ title, groups, onSelect }: MultilevelDropdownProps) => {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState<SubItem | null>(null);
  const [selectedGroup, setSelectedGroup ] = useState<Group | null>(null);

  const handleSelection = (subItem: SubItem | null) => {
    if (subItem) {
      setSelectedItem(subItem);
      onSelect(subItem.name);
      setOpen(!open);
    } else {
      setSelectedItem(null);
      setSelectedGroup(null);
      setOpen(!open);
    }

  };

  return (
    <MultilevelDropdownContext.Provider value={{handleSelection, selectedGroup, setSelectedGroup}}>
      <div tabIndex={0} onBlur={() => handleSelection(null)} className={clsx('dropdown',
        { 'dropdown__open': open})}>
        <div className={clsx('dropdown__trigger', {'dropdown__trigger__open': open})} onClick={() => handleSelection(null)}>
          { generateDropdownLabel(selectedGroup, selectedItem, title) }
          <VtmnIcon value={open ? 'arrow-drop-up-line' : 'arrow-drop-down-line'} size={20} color={open ? 'black' : 'white'} />
        </div>
        { open && (
          <ul>
            {groups?.map((group) =>
              isToDisplayGroup(selectedGroup, group) && <DropdownGroup key={group.id} group={group} />)}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </MultilevelDropdownContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default MultilevelDropdown;
```

The onBlur() event combned to the tabIndex is working nicely in my storybook. I don't understand what's happening. In my test, despite i click on another element it does not seem to close my dropdown.

Hope you can help and thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not use the `onBlur` event to handle "click outside of the parent div of this element". 
In this case, I am using the [useOnClickOutside](https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/) hook. 
When you will use that hook then your test logic should pass.